# Clicking on a value in dropdown #1 should automatically open the dropdown #2 and close dropdown #1

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

Closing the same dropdown in which a value is chosen is pretty standard. Now I want to increase user experience by **automatically opening the next drop-down for the user after choosing a value in the previous drop-down**. I personally am not very experienced with code, but the (Indian) web-building company that is building the website for my startup says this is not possible. Maybe I'm being unreasonable, but I feel like this shouldn't be too hard of a job.

Does anyone know if this is possible? I know they are using mean-stack (AngularJS, Node.JS, Express.js, MongoDB).

Thanks very much in forwards!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - please do not ask other people here to do your work.

Comment: Thanks:) Just need to know if it is possible, don't need them to do my work!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, you need to bind an onclick event on checkboxes/options, which on click will close parent div/dropdown and open parent.next() dropdown/div.

This is just one way.

There are many other ways to achieve the same.